# Laptop screen displaying white / static noise

Tags: laptop, display, gpu, laptop-display

I'm not sure how to describe this other than white noise, video [here](https://im6.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-6-cae25bc4846d.mp4).

Processor is an i7-7700HQ.

Render GPU is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti - just updated to driver 26.21.14.4166 12/06/2019.

Any idea how I can diagnose the issue?

Comment: That looks like an issue with the display itself (i.e. a hardware issue).

Comment: Update your BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers and test. If the white noise stays there, then I agree with the above that it would be a hardware issue

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue.